# howto conntect hp zbook 15 g2 to 2nd display over acer k272hul daisy chain incl. convert to DVI)

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi, displayport, daisychaining

here is my setup:

- laptop: hp zbook 15 g2 , no docking station
- acer k272hul (2560*1140)
- dell p2311H (1900*1080)

### the goal is

connect to both displays to to the laptop and run at max resolution. For this

- the acer is connected via DP and
- the dell (since only having DVI and VGA ports) with a VGA cable from laptop to dell

### problems

- picture is blurry on DELL which is bothersome. (prio 1)
- cable clutter (prio 2)

### idea

so i wanted to fix that and had the idea to connect the dell via the DP out of the acer but since the dell only has a DVI and VGA i'm using a DP to DVI cable.

unfortunately, the laptop (win7 + latest drivers) doens't detect the dell.

note, i covered the basics

- the zbook suport daisy chaining
- the acer support daisy chaining

  - the DP 1.2 is turned on
- the DP to DVI works on its own
- from what i have read DP -> DVI should work at the end of a daisy chain, but maybe not with these devices/cable?

### question 1:

so anyone out there that was successful to daisy chain the acer with DP -> DVI ?
or that can give tips to remedy the problem ?

### question 2:

since sharp picture has higher prio than cable clutter:

- any one there that has successfully used both, DP and thunderbolt ports (which also does DP according to the manual) to hook up 2 monitors?
- how does this work and what needs to be looked out for, e.g. cables and devices?

Answer (score 0):

i invested in the meantime into a 2nd WQHD display with DP 1.2. and that now is recognized. so daisy chaining with a DP2DVI cable aint working (with this hardware).